# Why does my Tkinter window sometimes not display at all?

Tags: python, tkinter

My Tkinter window displays correctly most of the time, but then sometimes, randomly, doesn't display. It's a major pain. I've tried various things (such as leaving out any Pygame rendering during the Tkinter window construction) and I've confirmed the window coordinates are exactly the same when displayed, or not displayed. I've tried to `lift` the window, I've tried to `force_focus` on the window, but nothing is working.

Here is my code:

```
# Function to take a postcode and station using Tkinter:
def first_time_setup():
    global test_w, test_r, default_colour

    master = Tk()
    master.withdraw()

    master.overrideredirect(1)
    back_img = PhotoImage(file=find_data_file('Outlooker_background.png'))
    back_label = Label(master, image=back_img)
    back_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
    back_label.image = back_img

    text_font = font.Font(family='Arial', size=12)
    button_font = font.Font(family='Calibri Light', size=11, weight="bold")

    master.columnconfigure(0, weight=3)
    e_weather = Entry(master, font=text_font, width=15)
    e_weather.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=(15, 5), sticky=E)
    b_weather = Button(master, text="TEST", font=button_font,
                       bg='light blue', command=lambda: test_weather(e_weather.get(), b_weather, b_done))
    b_weather.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=(0, 15), pady=(12, 0), sticky=E)

    e_rail = Entry(master, font=text_font, width=15)
    e_rail.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=E)
    b_rail = Button(master, text="TEST", font=button_font,
                    bg='light blue', command=lambda: test_rail(e_rail.get(), b_rail, b_done))
    b_rail.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=(0, 15), sticky=E)

    b_done = Button(master, text="DONE", font=button_font, state=DISABLED,
                    bg='light blue', command=lambda: testing_done(master))
    b_done.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=(0, 15), pady=10, sticky=E)

    if first_time:
        b_quit = Button(master, text="QUIT", font=button_font,
                        bg='light blue', command=lambda: sys.exit(0))
    else:
        b_quit = Button(master, text="EXIT", font=button_font,
                        bg='light blue', command=lambda: master.destroy())
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, (223, 296, 417, 134))
        pygame.display.flip()

    b_quit.grid(row=2, padx=15, pady=10, sticky=W)
    default_colour = b_quit.cget("background")

    master.update_idletasks()  # Update "requested size" from geometry manager
    x = (master.winfo_screenwidth() - 417) / 2
    y = (master.winfo_screenheight() - 134) / 2
    master.geometry("417x134+%d+%d" % (x, y))
    master.deiconify()
    master.lift()
    master.focus_force()
    e_weather.focus_set()
    master.mainloop()
```

As the window is displaying about half of the time, I consider my code to be fine, and this is possibly a fault with either Tkinter or even Windows? Does anybody know what is happening please?

EDIT: Here is the call to `first_time_setup`:

```
if first_time:
    first_time_setup()

first_time = False
```

So any further calls will trigger the `else` statement within the function.

Comment: How do you call `first_time_setup`?

Comment: @SneakyTurtle: I've edited the Question to show the call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of people have been asking this type of question lately where `overrideredirect` is involved. So here is a little longer response as to why it happens and (in this case) how you can potentially fix it. Once you execute the line `master.overrideredirect(1)`, window managers don't send focus or other event messages to the window. What might solve your problem is to do `master.overrideredirect(1)` at the very end of your initialization. Note also, that once you execute the command, the window manager essentially ignores the window. Try this experiment with `master.overrideredirect(1)` and `master.overrideredirect(0)` separately. Once the window is rendered, use the `<Alt-Tab>` keys to cycle through the windows. Notice that when `master.overrideredirect(1)`, the window does not show up in the window list to cycle through. Finally, if the user does `<Alt-Tab>` away from the window, there is no event sent to the application to detect this, and the *user may have a very difficult time setting focus back on the window*, depending on how many overlapping windows they have covering it.

Typically, it is unwise to have a borderless main window due to lack of user control of it. The reason `overrideredirect` exists is probably for enabling the creation of custom **temporary** utility and megawidgets like comboboxes and such.

Comment: Thank you! The 'master.overridredirect(1)' was a part of a code snippet I found for centring the tkinter window by getting the screen dimensions - I just assumed it was necessary to disable the window manager to do this, but admittedly didn't give it much thought. Schoolboy error. I've removed it completely (my window doesn't _have_ to borderless) and I've run it 4 or 5 times in a row and seems to have done the trick, and the window is still centred on the screen. You have answered my question both quickly and conclusively, so thanks again Ron.

Comment: > master.overrideredirect(1) at the very end of your initialization.

that fixed my issues. thanks