# Tkinter window sometimes disappear

Tags: python, tkinter

Good day !

I'm having an issue with tkinter that I can't solve by myself.
I want to display a countdown on a window that will be located over my taskbar, like in the image below.
[image]

What I wanted to do is to make my program run at startup and close when I shut my computer off. I really need this window to be over my taskbar, and I need it permanently too.
My problem is that it sometimes disappear.

While making various tests, I noted different situations :

- When I open a full screen window that will cover my taskbar, my program appear above this window, but disappears when I close the full screen window. If I reopen this window, my program reappers over it, and disappears as soon as I close the window.
- When I hover my mouse around an app that is open in my taskbar (for example when I want to select a specific tab in my browser) , my program disappears.
- When I do nothing on my computer, my program stays visible as I want. In general, it seems that if I don't interact with the taskbar, my program will stay visible.

I've read the answer to the question
[Why does my Tkinter window sometimes not display at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44869582/why-does-my-tkinter-window-sometimes-not-display-at-all) and tested several positions of the line

```
root.overrideredirect(1)
```

but nothing seemed to change. Here is my code :

```
import tkinter as tk
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import relativedelta
def diff(): #Computes the difference , in days/hours/minutes, between two dates 
    """
    Returns a string
    """
    

    date_2 = datetime(2020, 5, 4, 8, 00) 
    

    date_1 = datetime.now()
    
    #This will find the difference between the two dates
    difference = relativedelta.relativedelta(date_2, date_1)
    

    months = difference.months
    days = difference.days+months*30
    hours = difference.hours
    minutes = difference.minutes
    
    text=(str(days)+" jours "+str(hours)+" heures "+str(minutes)+" minutes ")
    return text #string

def update(): #Updating the window
    texte=str(diff())
    
    l.config(text="Temps restant avant CCP:\n "+texte) #That's the string that needs to update every minute
    root.after(1000, update)



root = tk.Tk()
root.overrideredirect(1)
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1) #This should make my window appear above everything
root.geometry("{0}x{1}+1300+1040".format(300, 40))
root.resizable(width=False, height=False) #Removing it doesn't change my problem
root['bg']="#d5dadc" #So that the background of the window matches my taskbar's color

l = tk.Label(text='Init...',bg="#d5dadc")
l.pack()

root.after(1000, update) #starts updating after 1 minute

root.mainloop()
```

Sorry if my answer has already been answered but all of the other questions I've found don't reproduce the same situation I'm in.

Thanks for your help !

Francesco

Comment: ***"My problem is that it sometimes disappear."***: There is no guarantee that a `.overrideredirect(1)` window is always the **top** window in the Window Manager stack. This approach may be a workaround: [check-if-window-is-in-background-tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60442386/check-if-window-is-in-background-tkinter/60443323)

Comment: Thanks stovfl ! To guarantee that my window is the top in the Window Manager stack, I used the line `root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)` . Maybe the problem is centered around this but I don't know why...

Comment: ***"located over my taskbar"***: You can't control the ***Window Manager stack***. Your `taskbar` is in general also defined as *always on top*. As soon as your Window Manger refreshes, the `taskbar` become priorty.

Comment: Oh ok thanks for the clarification. Does that mean what I'm trying to achieve is impossible? I couldn't find any way to detect when my program no longer is top 1 priority and I can't really make a loop that checks forever if my window is displayed or not ...

Comment: ***"couldn't find any way to detect ..."***: My given link show this. ***can't really make a loop***: You allready have a loop, the simplest solution is `.withdraw()` and `.deiconify()` within your `.after(...` loop. But this could lead to **flickering**.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer ! I found an acceptable solution, I put `root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)` inside my update function, and I update every 10ms instead of every 1000ms. Even if the refresh rate is really too much, it's a small program so not using much memory as it is constant in space use. It doesn't seem to have a problem with max recursive calls so I'll stick with that. Thanks for your help !